# Displaying multiple images using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I’m making a memory game using pygame and I need to display 16 images on a 4 by 4 grid. I made the 4x4 grid using a couple of for loops. I stored the images in a list variable. So far I can only get one image to display 16 times using the pygame.image.load() function. I’ve tried to google If there is some sort of loop I could run to display those images one by one from the list, but I’ve come up with nothing. The images also need to be in a random position every time the game is Played I’m pretty sure I know how to do that part I’m stuck on displaying the images on the window.

Any help is much appreciated Thanks.

Comment: If you posted the code instead of describing the code, this question would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two lists of images, one that simply holds the image bitmaps:

```
# Load in all the 16 images
memory_images = []
for filename in [ 'flower01.png', 'tree01.png', 'flower02.png', 'duck.png' ... ]
    new_image = pygame.image.load( filename )
    memory_images.append( new_image )
```

Another list can hold a mapping of image index to location.

```
import random

# make a list of random numbers with no repeats:
image_count = len( memory_images )  # should be 16 for a 4x4 grid
random_locations = random.sample( range( image_count ), image_count )
```

The `random_locations` variable holds the index of the image loaded, this is random but will be of a form like: `[7, 3, 9, 0, 2, 11, 12, 14, 15, 1, 4, 6, 8, 13, 5, 10]` with no-repeats.

So when drawing your 16 cells, at cell `[i]` draw `memory_images[ random_locations[ i ] ]`.

```
for i in range( 16 ):
    x, y = grid_locations[ i ]
    image = memory_images[ random_locations[ i ] ]
    screen.blit( image, ( x, y ) )
```

Comment: I ran your first for loop on my images and the program kinda works I get no error but when the window opens it only displays the 8th image 16 times instead of different images also I have to use the random.shuffle() function to get the list of images in a random order every time the program is run and the program just reads it left to right.